# Getting recursion error when creating button class

Tags: python, class, button

I am creating a button class for a python project and at runtime, I get the following error:

```
my_Button = Button(master)
[Previous line repeated 496 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is the classes I created:

```
from tkinter import *
import random


class Window:

    def __init__(self, master):
        master.title('Black Jack')
        master.configure(bg='green')
        master.geometry('500x500')


class Button:

    def __init__(self, master, text, font, x, y):
        master = master
        self.text = text
        self.font = font
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        my_Button = Button(master, text=text, font=font)
        my_Button.pack(x=x, y=y)
```

This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import Classes

Helvetica = font = ('Helvetica', 15, 'bold italic')
Times = font = ('times', 13, 'bold italic')

root = Tk()
window = Classes.Window(root)
playButton = Classes.Button(root, 'Play', font, 200, 200)
```

Why am I getting a recursion error? I am not using any loops.

Comment: Why does the Button have a Button? Perhaps the my_Button lines were an early experiment that needs to be deleted?

Comment: `my_Button = Button(master, text=text, font=font)` should be probably be outside of the `__init__` function, or possibly not exist at all. What do you think it's doing?

Comment: I think it's creating a button such as var=Button(). If it exists outside the _init_ how would create the button and add the vars to it?

Comment: `__init__` initialises the `Button`. When you call `Button(root, 'Play', font, 200, 200)` you are implicitly calling `Button.__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, you need to check the following code which would recursively call the `__init__` method.

`my_Button = Button(master, text=text, font=font)`

When you call the Button() method you are calling the `init` method each and every time. This would therefore get stuck in a loop. And the follwing line of code from what I understand will never execute due to the ongoing recursion.

`my_Button.pack(x=x, y=y)`

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with main loop and only to do with a recursive call to Button.

Comment: How is it recursively calling the Button? I have no loops.

Comment: Yes, you have no loops, but recursion is an alternative to loops. Your `Button` class is calling its own constructor which is recursion. (btw loops are sometimes seen as the way to avoid recursion and the consequential stack overflow).

Comment: i don't understand. How is it calling it's own constructor? Shouldn't the _init_ run once through the code and create that button and move on to the next line of the main code?

Comment: Its calling its own constructor through this line  `my_Button = Button(master, text=text, font=font)` in the `__init__` method. So each and every time it gets to this line it will recusively call the constructor method. And therfore this line `my_Button.pack(x=x, y=y)` will never be executed. Do read [here](https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/) to get better understanding on recusion